# Ram keeps maxing out then going back down to normal then maxing out again in 19.04

Tags: ram, 19.04

[Here is the strange behavior in my system monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdq5q.png)

I have a ryzen 1600, nvidia gtx 1060 on the 418 driver, 16gb ddr4 3000mhz ram, msi b450 tomahawk motherboard, and the gnome desktop environment

I noticed that suddenly my mouse would keep getting slow and my computer was freezing up for a few seconds and then it would go back to normal. I went into the system monitor to see if anything was going on and I see my ram increasing incredibly fast up from 1gb to 16gb and filling the swap within seconds and then going back down.

I tried restarting the PC to see if it would fix it and it started doing it again. I have been on this fresh 19.04 installation for about 2 weeks now and have not had this issue until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out which process this is, run the following in a terminal:

```
while true; 
do 
ps -o pid,user,%mem,command ax | sort -b -k3 -r | head -n 6 >> /tmp/mem-usage.txt;
sleep 3;
done
```

Let it run until the problem occurs, then you can inspect `/tmp/mem-usage.txt` to find out which process it is and alleviate the problem which of course depends on the process.

The code will loop and print the top 5 processes that are using memory every 3 seconds to `/tmp/mem-usage.txt`. Once you have seen the problem, to stop the loop you hit `Ctrl+C` in the terminal window and then inspect the file.

Comment: The problem seems to have stopped happening after my PC went to into sleep mode and came back. I ran this command by my ram usage is sitting at 1.7gb steady now so I don't think it will show the problem now unfortunately.

Comment: The most important thing is that the problem seems to have "fixed itself" (I hate those). Use my instructions if it happens again to find the culprit and nuke it from orbit. ;-)